# how to avoid the page reload after clicking the ng-click in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular

if i click the button after page should not reload it should be static and the count and image should change as per my logic

```
event.preventDefault();


<a class="button" 
   ng-click="Like(Post)" 
   ng-if="Post.uid =='true'" 
   href="/Home/HomePage" 
   style="text-decoration:none;" 
   ng-init="likeDetails(Post)">
  <input type="image" 
         alt="" 
         src="~/Images/like.png" 
         style="max-height:20px; max-width:20px;" />
    &nbsp;Like<span class="badge">{{Post.likes}}</span>
</a>
<a ng-click="Like(Post)" 
   ng-if="Post.uid !='true'" 
   href="/Home/HomePage" 
   style="text-decoration:none;" 
   ng-init="likeDetails(Post)">
                                <input type="image" alt="" src="~/Images/liked.png" style="max-height:20px; max-width:20px;" />&nbsp;Like<span class="badge">{{Post.likes}}</span>
                            </a>
```

page is reloading after clicking the ng-click

Comment: Set `href="#" ` instead of `href="/Home/HomePage"`.

Comment: Agree with the @Karan's suggestion. Check it and do let us know if you are still facing problem !

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply, I used your suggestion but its not working...